# How to merge multiples columns of a table into 1 in R

Tags: r, merge

I have a data frame (`control.sub`) containing multiple columns (`t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6`). I want to merge all these columns into one, also NA should be removed.

```
> control.sub
                             t1                         t2                         t3                         t4
29   5500024017802120306174.H01 5500024017802120306174.G02 5500024017802120306174.E03 5500024017802120306174.D04
810  5500024030401071707292.H01 5500024030401071707292.G02 5500024030401071707292.E03 5500024030401071707292.D04
4693 5500024035736031208612.G08 5500024035736031208612.E09 5500024035736031208612.D10 5500024035736031208612.B11
                             t5                         t6
29   5500024017802120306174.B05 5500024017802120306174.A06
810  5500024030401071707292.B05 5500024030401071707292.A06
4693 5500024035736031208612.A12                       <NA>
```

I want the final outcome as:

```
> control.sub
                                 t1
    29   5500024017802120306174.H01 5500024017802120306174.G02 5500024017802120306174.E03 5500024017802120306174.D04
    810  5500024030401071707292.H01 5500024030401071707292.G02 5500024030401071707292.E03 5500024030401071707292.D04
    4693 5500024035736031208612.G08 5500024035736031208612.E09 5500024035736031208612.D10 5500024035736031208612.B11

       5500024017802120306174.B05 5500024017802120306174.A06
      5500024030401071707292.B05 5500024030401071707292.A06
     5500024035736031208612.A12
```

One columns (t1) containing all values.

Comment: See `?paste` if you are trying to concatenate strings

Comment: paste is concatenating the columns I am giving, I don't want to concatenate, I want them in separate rows. : > control.sub$Mix <-paste(control.sub[,1], control.sub[,2],collapse=NULL, sep=" ")
> control.sub$Mix
[1] "5500024017802120306174.H01 5500024017802120306174.G02" "5500024030401071707292.H01 5500024030401071707292.G02"
[3] "5500024035736031208612.G08 5500024035736031208612.E09"

Comment: you need to use `collapse=' '`, I will show you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slightly more [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example):

```
df <- data.frame(t1 = c(letters[1:5],NA), t2 = c(NA, LETTERS[6:10]), 
                 t3 = c(11:12,NA,13:15), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df
#     t1   t2 t3
# 1    a <NA> 11
# 2    b    F 12
# 3    c    G NA
# 4    d    H 13
# 5    e    I 14
# 6 <NA>    J 15


df2 <- data.frame(t1 = apply(df, 1, function(s) paste(s[!is.na(s)], collapse=" ")) )

df2
#       t1
# 1   a 11
# 2 b F 12
# 3    c G
# 4 d H 13
# 5 e I 14
# 6   J 15
```

**EDIT**

I think the OP is looking for this, but his/her example is wrong:

```
unlist_not_na <- function(df){
  v <- unlist(df)
  v[!is.na(v)]
}
df3 <- data.frame(t1 = unlist_not_na(df))

df3
#     t1
# t11  a
# t12  b
# t13  c
# t14  d
# t15  e
# t22  F
# t23  G
# t24  H
# t25  I
# t26  J
# t31 11
# t32 12
# t34 13
# t35 14
# t36 15
```

Comment: Problem is here it is concatenating all columns value. for example for row1 generating 1 a 11, while i want one value in one row, (row1= 1, row2= a, row3 = 11 and so on...)

Comment: @user3253470 Your example is wrong then because the row numbers stay the same: 29, 810, 4693.

Comment: you are right there are only 3 rows but I want as many rows as many values.

Comment: @user3253470 see my edit -- but you should really work on asking the question well, and providing a minimally reproducible (and correct) example.

Comment: @user3253470 happy to help, please click the check mark next to the answer if you wish to accept it

Comment: If this is my control.sub: > control.sub
                t1   t2 t3   t4   t5   t6
507 EC2004030514AA <NA> NA <NA> <NA> <NA>
511 EC2004041408AA <NA> NA <NA> <NA> <NA>
569 EC2004070108AA <NA> NA <NA> <NA> <NA>
Then after applying your proposed method, result I am getting is: > df3
    t1
t11 37
t12 41
t13 55
whereas I want the result as : )
> df3
 > t1
t11 EC2004030514AA
t12 EC2004041408AA
t13 EC2004070108AA
Please guide me how I can get that ??

Comment: Can you help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35484595/data-frame-merge-and-selection-of-values-which-are-common-in-2-data-frames

Answer (score 0):

The following code works, but I don't know if anyone would consider it "optimal":

```
var <- as.vector(do.call('c',control.sub))
```

I would suggest going up higher in your code where you generate control.sub (if that is possible) and then manipulate the output format there.

If your variables are factors(you can check this by running:)

```
sapply(control.sub,class)
```

then you should first run:

```
controlsub<-lapply(control.sub,as.character)
```

---

EDIT: this is better:

```
 var <- unlist(control.sub)
```

Comment: probably it is returning me the indexes of the values. I want the values not the indexes. > var
 [1] 133 123 123 123 123  91 161 151 151 151 151 113 249 225 225 225 225  NA

Comment: make sure your columns aren't factors and try my new solution too.

Comment: Still the same problem: > var <- as.vector(do.call('c',control.sub))
> var
 [1] 133 161 249 123 151 225 123 151 225 123 151 225 123 151 225  91 113  NA

Comment: I said to make sure your variables weren't factors first.

Comment: I am sorry I don't know how to check this thing...!

Comment: sapply(control.sub,class).
If they are factors, just make them all character first: control.sub<-sapply(control.sub,as.character)

Comment: after converting them into characters, I am getting the following error:> var <- as.vector(do.call('c',control.sub))
Error in do.call("c", control.sub) : second argument must be a list

Comment: just wrap control.sub in as.list()