# Merge replicate data from identical columns in different csv files

Tags: r, csv, merge

I'm trying to merge replicate data from two columns from different csv files into a single column (of the same name). Each row is a different timepoint. I feel like this should be easy, but I'm new to coding and using the merge or rbind functions haven't gotten me very far.

For example: 
data1

A

0 1

2 1

4 1

data2

A

0 2

2 2

4 2

I want: 
data_combined

A

0 1 2

2 1 2

4 1 2

Thanks for any help!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for tips on how to format your questions to get better help. It's hard to tell what your data looks like in it's current format, using the output of `dput` would be helpful.

Comment: I think this answer was already asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098546/how-to-merge-multiples-columns-of-a-table-into-1-in-r . have a good day

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, here is your answer:

```
data_combined <- data.frame(data1, data2[,2])
```

if it is not what you meant, explain more so that I could help you